# SQL Exception When Sending values from jtable to sql

Tags: java, sql-server, swing

I am stuck in a problem. When I try to send data from jtable to sql database through stored procedure. here what I am doing:

inserting data to jtable

```
String b= jLabel116.getText(),c=jTextField6.getText(),e=jTextField20.getText(),f=jTextField25.getText(),g=jTextField48.getText();

float x,y,z;
x=Float.parseFloat(jTextField25.getText());
y=Float.parseFloat(jTextField48.getText());
z=x*y;
String total1=String.valueOf(z);

DefaultTableModel df = (DefaultTableModel) jTable5.getModel();
df.addRow(new Object[]{b,c,d,f,g,total1});
int rowsCount = jTable5.getRowCount();
int Price = 0,Qty=0, total=0;
for(int i=0;i<rowsCount;i++){
Price += Integer.parseInt(jTable5.getValueAt(i,3).toString());
Qty += Integer.parseInt(jTable5.getValueAt(i,4).toString());  
}
total = Price*Qty;
System.out.println(total);
jTextField26.setText(String.valueOf(total));
jTextField51.setText(String.valueOf(total));
jTextField50.setText(String.valueOf(Qty));
jTable5.setModel(df);
```

Sending Data to Database

```
try{
    DefaultTableModel df = new DefaultTableModel();
    df=(DefaultTableModel) jTable5.getModel();
             CallableStatement cs=m.XC.prepareCall("call Prod_SALE (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");    
        for (int i = 0; i < df.getRowCount(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < df.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                Object o = df.getValueAt(i, j);
                System.out.println("object from table is  : " +o);
            cs.setString(j+1, (String)o);
          cs.addBatch();
            }
      cs.executeBatch();
          cs.clearParameters();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
         ex.printStackTrace();
```

Error Exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter-Set has missing values.
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.addBatch(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:1546)
```

Please help me....I am unable to solve it

Comment: LOL...........No Body can solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You call `addBatch` in the **inner loop** (variable `j`) after you have set **one** parameter. Obviously this fails since you have 8 parameters. The Javadoc of `PreparedStatement.addBatch` says:

> Adds a set of parameters to this PreparedStatement object's batch of
>   commands.

You need to move the call to `addBatch` out of the inner loop.
(And probably the `executeBatch` should be moved out of the outer loop (variable `i`) too.

```
DefaultTableModel df = (DefaultTableModel) jTable5.getModel();
CallableStatement cs=m.XC.prepareCall("call Prod_SALE (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");    
for (int i = 0; i < df.getRowCount(); i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < df.getColumnCount(); j++) 
    {
        Object o = df.getValueAt(i, j);
        System.out.println("object from table is  : " +o);
        cs.setString(j+1, (String)o);
    }
    cs.addBatch();
}
cs.executeBatch();
```

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, you have not set all values in your SQL.

Comment: but I am unable to understand which values?

Comment: Are you sure that df.getColumnCount() gives you the same number of columns that you have in the call Prod_SALE (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ?

Comment: Unfortunately most DB's don't offer much help in which parameter is missing. Just make sure all of them are set.